# Using beginthread with structure of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, pointers, structure

I'm working on a project in which I have to use a structure of pointers as input arguments into a thread. My code looks something like this:

```
struct coord
{
    double* xPos;
    double* yPos;
};

void cdecl foo( void* inData)
{
    coord* my_data = (coord*) inData;

    printf("Thread values:\n");
    printf("xVal: %f\n", *(my_data->xPos) );
    printf("yVal: %f\n", *(my_data->yPos) );
}
```

and the main's body looks something like this:

```
{
    double startX = 10;
    double startY = 10;
    /* declare variables to hold the incoming values */
    coord inData;

    inData.xPos = &startX;
    inData.yPos = &startY;

    printf("Initial values:\n");
    printf("xVal: %f\n", *(inData.xPos) );
    printf("yVal: %f\n", *(inData.yPos) );

    _beginthread( foo, 0, (void*) &inData );
}
```

Why is my program displaying different values for the main and thread, and how do I correct it?

Comment: By the time your thread runs, main() may have already returned. Either pass data to thread by value, or make sure that the pointed to values still exist when the thread reads them. In this case `HANDLE h=(HANDLE)_beginthread... ; WaitForSingleObject(h);` would make sure that main doesn't return until the thread does. Also you should close the thread handle with _endthread().

Comment: You should use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring your structure and double values on the stack and once that method returns (after `_beginthread()` returns) the stack is removed leading to undefined behaviour.

You need to allocate the structure on the heap, including the `double` values.  You'll also need to manage this allocated memory.

Also, I don't see why you are using `double *` as opposed to simply `double`.

**EDIT**: Some sample code.  This allocates the structure on the heap and passes the allocated data back to the caller.  There is still some work to do with thread synchronization, which is outside the scope of this question:

```
struct coord
{
    double xPos;
    double yPos;
};

void cdecl foo(void* inData)
{
    coord* my_data = (coord*) inData;

    printf("Thread values:\n");
    printf("xVal: %f\n", my_data->xPos);
    printf("yVal: %f\n", my_data->yPos);
}

coord *startThread()
{
    coord *inData = new coord;
    inData->xPos = 10;
    inData->yPos = 10;

    _beginthread( foo, 0, (void*) inData );
    return inData;
}

int main()
{
    coord *data = startThread();
    printf("Initial values:\n");
    printf("xVal: %f\n", data->xPos);
    printf("yVal: %f\n", data->yPos);

    // TODO: wait for thread

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please show a brief sample? I'm using a pointer because the thread would, in my real program, update coordinates on the fly for another function (not included here) to use.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
coord inData;
```

to

```
static coord inData;
```